# Calculating Big "O" for the following example

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Let's say I have a following code sample:

```
int number;
for(int i = 0; i < A; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < B; j++)
        if(i == j) // some condition...
            do{
                number = rand(); 
            }while(number > 100);
```

I would like to know the Big "O" for this example. Outer loops are O(A * B), but I'm not sure what to think about the `do-while` loop and it's Big "O". In the worst case scenario it can be an infinite loop and in the best case O(1) and ignored.

Edit: updated condition inside the `if` statement (replaced function call with a simple comparison).

Comment: The answer totally depends on the implementation of `someCondition()`, and also it depends on what range of value `rand()` can return.  You should include this information in your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If `if` statement would not be a function call, but something like `i == j` then I presume the `if` statement would be O(1)? `rand()` can return any `int` number. Could you please explain how it's range is important in this case, inside the `do-while` loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `rand()` is a random function and it has a specified range of output, we can say the `do while` statement is O(1).
So, it depends on the `someCondition()` function.

Total complexity is O(A * B) * O(someCondition).

Comment: If `if` statement would not be a function call, but something like `i == j` then I presume the `if` statement would be O(1)?

Comment: Also, I really don't understand why the `do-while` complexity is O(1) in this case?

Comment: If the `if` statement is not a function call, then complexity will be O(A*B)

Comment: Assume the output of the `rand()` function has a range of 0 to MAX_NUM. Then, the probability of the number being smaller than 100 is 100/MAX_NUM. So, the `do while` statement breaks in MAX_NUM/100 times on the average. So, we can say the complexity of the `do while` is O(MAX_NUM/100)=O(1).

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks.

Comment: Did you maybe made a mistake in MAX_NUM/100 and O(MAX_NUM/100)? If, for example, I would want to make sure do-while avoids generating a duplicate number then it would be like MAX_NUM/1 probability, which is very big. Should it perhaps be 100/MAX_NUM in both cases?

Comment: @Tracer: the point is it doesn't matter, it can be treated as a constant. It doesn't contribute to asymptotic growth.